# How to delay execution within ThreadPool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, web-scraping, threadpool

I've written a script in python using `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` to handle multiple requests concurrently and do the scraping process robust. The parser is doing it's job perfectly.

As I have noticed in several scripts that there should be a delay within the scraping process when it is created using ***multiprocessing***, I would like to put a delay within my below script as well.

***However, This is where I'm stuck and can't find out the right position to put that delay.***

This is my script so far:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

url = "http://srar.com/roster/index.php?agent_search=a"

def get_links(link):
    completelinks = []
    res = requests.get(link)  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    for items in soup.select("table.border tr"):
        if not items.select("td a[href^='index.php?agent']"):continue
        data = [urljoin(link,item.get("href")) for item in items.select("td a[href^='index.php?agent']")]
        completelinks.extend(data)
    return completelinks

def get_info(nlink):
    req = requests.get(nlink)
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
    for tr in sauce.select("table[style$='1px;'] tr")[1:]:
        table = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select("td")]
        print(table)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ThreadPool(20).map(get_info, get_links(url))
```

***Once again: all i need to know is the right position within my script to put a delay.***

Comment: Before you return `return completelinks`.

Comment: There are still two ways I can put that delay. Which way you meant @stovfl? Please check out ***[this image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4zvpt09pus04na/Untitled.jpg?dl=0)*** to clarify. Thanks a lot.

Comment: WE **dont** LIKE IMAGES! [Edit] your Question instead. [Edit] your Question and elaborate, the **pro** and **con** of the **two** ways? Read about [Section: Lines and Indentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_syntax.htm).

Comment: Don't get me wrong @stovfl. I do know that images are not accepted here. However, I uploaded that image to be sure which way you meant. I erected this question (based on your comment) only because your suggested position of putting delay is not that specific as I can use that in two ways. By the way, I have a little knowledge about indentation.

Comment: Which conclusion did you get about the **pro** and **con** of the two ways?

Comment: If I could have figured that out myself, I would not have created this post @stovfl. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Consider deleting this question.

Comment: Why!!! Just because I could not get any satisfactory answer from you or the question is unclear or there is anything I should have added to my existing question @stovfl?

Comment: You want to put a delay in between the `get_info` calls so they are not made all at once, right?

Comment: Do you mean - the delay should be placed within `get_info()` function and `get_links()` function should be as it is @Darkonaut? I don't really understand which will be better. Awaiting your response. Btw, I do not wish to put a delay just because I require it; rather, I wish to follow how multiprocessing suggests in such cases. Thanks.

Comment: It's not obvious what you're trying to achieve. Multithreading doesn't need you to introduce delays, but you could hit some rate limiting barriers from the target url when you fire all requests at once. So it's really up to you to clear first what your goal is in putting a delay somewhere at all.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity @Darkonaut and yes ***rate limiting barriers*** is surely a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For putting a delay in between your multiple `requests.get()` calls, located within `get_info`, you would have to expand `get_info` with a delay-argument, which it can take as input to a `time.sleep()` call. Since all your worker-threads start at once, your delays have to be cumulative for every call. Meaning, when you want your delay between the `requests.get()` calls to be 0.5 seconds, your list of delays you are passing along into the pool-method would look like [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5 ...].

For not having to alter `get_info` itself, I'm using a decorator in the example below to extend `get_info` with a delay parameter and a `time.sleep(delay)` call. Note that I'm passing the delays along the other argument for `get_info` in the `pool.starmap` call.

```
import logging
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from functools import wraps

def delayed(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(delay, *args, **kwargs):
        time.sleep(delay)  # <--
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@delayed
def get_info(nlink):
    info = nlink + '_info'
    logger.info(msg=info)
    return info


def get_links(n):
    return [f'link{i}' for i in range(n)]


def init_logging(level=logging.DEBUG):
    fmt = '[%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(threadName)s' \
          ' %(funcName)s()] --- %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(format=fmt, level=level)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    DELAY = 0.5

    init_logging()
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    links = get_links(10) # ['link0', 'link1', 'link2', ...]
    delays = (x * DELAY for x in range(0, len(links)))
    arguments = zip(delays, links) # (0.0, 'link0'), (0.5, 'link1'), ...

    with ThreadPool(10) as pool:
        result = pool.starmap(get_info, arguments)
        print(result)
```

Example Output:

```
[2018-10-03 22:04:14,221 INFO     Thread-8 get_info()] --- link0_info
[2018-10-03 22:04:14,721 INFO     Thread-5 get_info()] --- link1_info
[2018-10-03 22:04:15,221 INFO     Thread-3 get_info()] --- link2_info
[2018-10-03 22:04:15,722 INFO     Thread-4 get_info()] --- link3_info
[2018-10-03 22:04:16,223 INFO     Thread-1 get_info()] --- link4_info
[2018-10-03 22:04:16,723 INFO     Thread-6 get_info()] --- link5_info
[2018-10-03 22:04:17,224 INFO     Thread-7 get_info()] --- link6_info
[2018-10-03 22:04:17,723 INFO     Thread-10 get_info()] --- link7_info
[2018-10-03 22:04:18,225 INFO     Thread-9 get_info()] --- link8_info
[2018-10-03 22:04:18,722 INFO     Thread-2 get_info()] --- link9_info
['link0_info', 'link1_info', 'link2_info', 'link3_info', 'link4_info', 
'link5_info', 'link6_info', 'link7_info', 'link8_info', 'link9_info']
```

Comment: Late to notice your answer. Much appreciated.